# Union of Ranges out of order

Tags: arrays, excel, union, vba

I am trying to copy various ranges in a certain order, and than paste them from a workbook into a different workbook.

Currently

I have set my ranges eg

```
Set rg = ws1.Range("A2:A" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)
Set rg1 = ws1.Range("Z2:Z" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)
Set rg2 = ws1.Range("C2:C" & i).Offset(rowOffset:=1, columnOffset:=0)

Set TradesCopy = Union(rg, rg1, rg2)
```

So typically what should happen is that it should be pasting in those ranges in that order (rg, rg1, rg2),

however this is being pasted rg, rg2, rg1

Can anyone tell me what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: As you can see for yourself, `Union` is automatically sorting the ranges within and since `C` comes before `Z` the ´C` becomes the middle one between column `A` and column `Z`. If you want a different order then you have two choices (as far as I can tell): (1) copy one range at a time or at least first `Union(rg, rg1)` and then `rg2` or (2) you create a two-dimensional array in which you paste the ranges in the order you desire and then paste that array back to the destination sheet. BTW, ordering is normal. Just consider `Union(Range("A1:D1"), Range("B1:C2"), Range("A2"), Range("D2"))`.

Comment: Can you please give me example using the above context how to do a two-dimensional array, the reason I did unions as I have been told you can order to your preference

Comment: I already know that solution, but I am keen to get clarity on these as I am moving lot of data from different workbooks,thank you ralph

Comment: @Jeeped Maybe you don't want to post a solution either? user3287522 doesn't seem very appreciative and is very likely not to accept your answer or even up-vote you. So, what's the point?

Comment: @Ralph  - ... besides, he/she '*already know that solution*'.

Comment: Jeeped I know this solution (1) copy one range at a time or at least first Union(rg, rg1) and then rg2 or (2),do you have a better one, your help appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you build a 2-D array of the values from the worksheet in the order you want them, you can put them in any order and it will be faster than multiple Copy & Paste operations.

```
Sub wqewqteq()
    Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long, lr As Long
    Dim vCOLs As Variant, vVALs As Variant, vSRCs As Variant

    vCOLs = Array(1, 26, 3)     'could also be Array("A", "Z", "C")

    With Worksheets("Sheet8")
        lr = Application.Max(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row, _
                             .Cells(.Rows.Count, "Z").End(xlUp).Row)
        vSRCs = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lr, "Z")).Value2
        ReDim vVALs(1 To lr - 1, 1 To UBound(vCOLs) + 1)

        For a = 1 To lr - 1
            For b = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
                vVALs(a, b + 1) = vSRCs(a, vCOLs(b))
            Next b
        Next a

        .Cells(2, "AB").Resize(UBound(vVALs, 1), UBound(vVALs, 2)) = vVALs

    End With

End Sub
```

I could find no mention of a specific destination so I used AB2 on the same worksheet.

Remember that you are dealing with both 1-D and 2-D arrays here. 1-D arrays default with a lower boundary of zero (lbound(vCOLs) == 0); 2-D arrays default with a lower boundary of one for each rank (lbound(vVALs, 1) == lbound(vVALs, 2) == 1).