# Create a 2D array from disjoint columns

Tags: vba, excel, range, union

I have a large Excel VBA macro (which cannot be modified) that accepts a range as input. It currently runs on large ranges via:

```
CustomFunc(Range("A10:I110"), outputFileName)
```

Now, I need to change a few calls this function to use a different column in place of column `A` which has a very different set of strings. I've tried to combine columns in the following ways, but not of them seem to work (function is complaining about incompatible types, so I think that the concatenation of columns I'm attempting isn't working):

```
CustomFunc(Range("X10:X110,B10:I110"), outputFileName)
CustomFunc(Union(Range("X10:X110"), Range("B10:I110")), outputFileName)
```

[I've also tried a function that is supposed to help me accomplish this via VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/110014/concatenate-disjoint-excel-ranges-to-use-as-a-single-range-in-a-formula), but the result is a `variant` rather than a range, so I can't use it to generate the input to `CustomFunc`.

How can I generate a concatenated set of columns and present it as a range to my function `CustomFunc`?

## Edit

[It appears that the `Union` function disregards order.](https://www.ozgrid.com/forum/forum/help-forums/excel-general/26232-union-ignores-order-of-arguments)

## NEW QUESTION:

How can I create an array from two ranges, i.e. `X10:X110` and `B10:I110` to create a `9x100` array of items, with the `X` column being the first/left-most column?

Comment: Either copy the discontiguous union to a contiguous range on a blank worksheet or rewrite your original to accept both contiguous and discontiguous ranges.

Comment: @Jeeped So, there's no way with VBA to dynamically create a range? Is there any way to create a `variant` from the data and present it as a `range`? Even it it burns up a lot of RAM, I'd take an automated solution via VBA code over duplicating dozens of thousand-line worksheets.

Comment: Sure, you can create a 2-D variant array but whether or not that is accepted as a range by the original function is going to depend on the coding.

Comment: @Jeeped Is there any way to type-convert/cast/export a variant array to `range`? I'm not at all familiar with VBA, and the last time I used it was over a decade ago.

Comment: No, a variant array doesn't have a parent worksheet but you can write code that works for both.

Comment: Hum, I just made a test with a custom function taking a range, used `Union` and the range got passed to the function correctly. Is there anything else to know about this function?

Comment: Not sure whether this is a typo, but in the example above, the two parts of the range have a different number of rows ie starting at B10 and X0, but both end at 110. Could that be an issue for the custom function?

Comment: Is the "Type Mismatch" error triggered as soon as the function is called (with the first argument of your function getting highlighted) or is it giving you the error further down inside the function?

Comment: I'm asking because if you have any cells that contains a number, the line `out_string = val1 + " some text " + val2 + " more text " + val3` will also give you a "Type Mismatch" error as VBA tries to add a string to a number. To avoid this, you would need to use `&` instead of `+` when concatenating strings.

Comment: @DecimalTurn It looks like your `&` suggestion helped. From what I've figured out, the `X10:X110` is ignored entirely, and VBA is acting as it I just gave it `B10:B110` rather than `Union(Range(X10:X110), Range(B10:I110))`.

Comment: @DecimalTurn [This question seems very similar to the issue I'm encountering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42985489/union-of-ranges-out-of-order), but doesn't solve it. It seems that VBA isn't preserving the order of arguments I provide.

Comment: For the new question: @Jeeped 's answer in that question seems a good solution to me. You would copy the data to another worksheet to make it in the right order and then pickup the range from that other worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the Union object on non-continuous column ranges and passing it to a function or sub procedure, looping through the rows might give you something different than what you expect. It's almost like VBA considers the two columns to be **stacked**.

For example, if you run the macro **test** in the code below, you will see that looping though the rows means that you are looping though each cells of the 2 columns.

```
Sub test()
    Call SelectRowByRow(Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("C1:C3")))
End Sub

Sub SelectRowByRow(rng As Range)

    Dim r As Range, i As Integer
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        r.Select
        i = i + 1
        MsgBox "Row " & i
    Next

End Sub
```

This gets a little messy if some columns are contiguous, but not all. For example, with **test2**, you'll see that column C and D are consider as a seperate block from column A, but it will consider their rows together.

```
Sub test2()
    Call SelectRowByRow(Union(Range("A1:A3"), Range("C1:C3"), Range("D1:D3")))
End Sub
```

Because of this, I would suggest to loop **through columns instead**.

**NEW QUESTION:**

If you only have 2 ranges, you could use a function like this:

```
Function UnionOrdered(rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range) As Range

    Dim wksTemp As Worksheet
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wksTemp = Sheets("TempUnion")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If wksTemp Is Nothing Then
        Set wksTemp = Sheets.Add
        wksTemp.Name = "TempUnion"
        wksTemp.Visible = False
    End If

    wksTemp.Cells.Clear
    rng1.Parent.Activate
    wksTemp.Cells(1, 1).Resize(rng1.Rows.Count, rng1.Columns.Count).Value2 = rng1.Value2
    wksTemp.Cells(1, 1 + rng1.Columns.Count).Resize(rng2.Rows.Count, rng2.Columns.Count).Value2 = rng2.Value2

    Set UnionOrdered = wksTemp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

End Function
```

It will make use of a hidden sheet to copy the content of the specified range in order to select the range in the right order.